# set Host in grpc-dart

Tags: dart, grpc, grpc-go

Is there a way to set Host in grpc-dart with with insecure connection, I have looked at [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dart/blob/master/lib/src/client/options.dart) but can not find a way?

Just need to set: `authority`

It should be similar to this in go - example setting host `serverHostOverride`:(note I can set host AND run WithInsecure connection)

```
var (
    serverAddr         = flag.String("server_addr", "127.0.0.1:8080", "The server address in the format of host:port")
    serverHostOverride = flag.String("server_host_override", "", "")
    insecure           = flag.Bool("insecure", false, "Set to true to skip SSL validation")
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    var opts []grpc.DialOption
    if *serverHostOverride != "" {
        opts = append(opts, grpc.WithAuthority(*serverHostOverride))
    }
    if *insecure {
        opts = append(opts, grpc.WithInsecure())
    }

    conn, err := grpc.Dial(*serverAddr, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("fail to dial: %v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    client := pb.NewPingServiceClient(conn)

    ping(client, "hello")
    pingStream(client, "hello")
}
```